# Могу ли я использовать настройки графика из библиотеки Chart.js используя библиотеку vue3-chart-v2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, диаграммы

Насколько я понял, библиотека vue3-chart-v2 это обертка библиотеки Chart.js.
Вот тут так написано [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://bestofvue.com/repo/vutran6853-vue3-chart-v2)

Мне нужно отключить рисование линий в графике, если я могу использовать настройки из библиотеки Chart.js то как я могу передать параметры которые вызвали бы отключение анимации линий?
Вот ссылка на именно этот пункт [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/performance.html)

Если нет я не могу этого делать, то как мне отключить анимацию линий в библиотеке vue3-chart-v2, вот документация в которой ничего не сказано об этом. https://vue3-chart-v2.netlify.app/

**Мой компонент графика, в котором нужно отключить отрисовку линий.**

```
<script>
import { Line } from "vue3-chart-v2";

export default {
  extends: Line ,

  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    title:{
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    
  },

  watch: {
    dataset: {
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
/*         console.log("newValue",newValue) */
        if (newValue ) {
          let chartData = {
            labels: this.dataset["x"],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "First Y Data 1",
                hidden: true,
                showLine:true,
              
                backgroundColor :"rgb(185, 223, 250, 1)",
                borderColor: "rgb(57, 86, 204, 1)",
                data: this.dataset["y_portf"]
   
              },
                 {
                label: "Second Y Data 2",
                showLine:true,

                backgroundColor :"rgb(247, 173, 186, 1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(201, 26, 41, 1)",
                data: this.dataset["y_struct"]
              },
            ],
          };

          this.$nextTick().then(() => {
            this.renderChart(chartData, {
              responsive: true,
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: this.title,
              },
            });
          });
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },


  mounted() {
/*     console.log("Данные data: ", this.dataset) */
    
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: первое что бросается в глаза то что у Вас true вместо false как указано [тут](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/performance.html#disable-line-drawing)

Comment: Так это просто линия, которая будет проведена через точки. Меня интересует как мне отключить анимацию на графиках ?

Comment: я прочел это `Мне нужно отключить рисование линий в графике...` и подумал чо речь идет про линии а не про анимацию, нужно уточнить вопрос

Comment: Уточню, простите..

Comment: `animation: false` - это нужно прописать в опции

Comment: Я не понимаю где это прописать в моем коде..

Comment: в Вашем, коде их нет насколько я вижу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создал проект [в песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-with-dynamic-data-forked-rmbtu?file=/src/App.vue) там в 24 строке отключена анимация:

```
  data() {
    return {
      state: {
        chartData: {},  // <- данные
        chartOptions: { // <-------.
          responsive: true, //     |  
          animation: false, //   опции
        },              // <-------'
      },
    };
  },
```

Кнопка `Randomize` позволяет смотреть смену графиков без анимации.
Дополнительно для изучения работы могут пригодится [официальные песочницы с примерами](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/vue3-chart-v2)